# How to stop blocking linux kernel thread

Tags: linux-kernel

Suppose I have two linux kernel threads, master thread and worker thread. Master uses `kthread_run()` to create worker. While worker is accepting socket connection and blocking, master calls `kthread_stop()` to stop worker.

Because worker is blocking on accepting operation and cannot exit, the `kthread_stop()` inside master will not return.

What should I do to kill worker thread from master in graceful way? Thanks.

Comment: Is the worker thread blocking in your own code or blocking somewhere else in the kernel?

Comment: Worker thread is blocking in kernel like reading or networking operation.

Comment: If it's not in your code, there's probably not much you can do. I suspect that the worker thread is woken by the `kthread_stop()` call, checks whether the condition it is waiting for has happened, decides it hasn't happened yet, and goes back to its waiting state. To change its behavior, you would have to modify the checking code to test the result of `kthread_should_stop()` and take appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a timeout for the blocking socket the worker is reading from:

```
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 0;  /* 100 ms Timeout */
tv.tv_usec = 100000;
kernel_setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv, sizeof(struct timeval));
```

Whenever the recv call returns you check for kthread_should_stop(). With 100ms timeout there should be almost zero polling overheads.